# Finding a French immigration lawyer

Tags: legal, france

Can anyone tell me how to find a good and reasonably priced English-speaking French immigration consultant/lawyer? I have had a long-stay visa refusal (the reason for refusal was "risk to public order/public security/health") and I would like to lodge an appeal against the decision, but as I am in the UK I do not know any French immigration consultants.

I am planning to attach my UK police certificate, which has no criminal record, to improve my appeal.

My previous immigration consultant recommended that I contact a lawyer specialized in administrative litigation, as this was not their area of expertise.

Comment: A quick internet search brings up a fairly long list of possibilities. You could try searching on https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/ What did your immigration consultant recommend as a means of finding a suitable lawyer? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Traveller how is someone qualified in the UK going to be helpful with a matter concerning French law?

Comment: @phoog UK-based law firms may have ‘international’ teams with appropriate expertise.

Comment: @phoog do you think appeal against refusal with such reason "risk to public security/public order/ health" would be effective? And appeal can lead me to get a visa?

Comment: Whether such an appeal would be effective depends on the facts of the case and on the basis of the appeal, neither of which you have said much about.

Comment: @phoog I do not know why my application was refused with this reason as I have no criminal record or never visited Schengen area so no over stay there.Nor even any overstay in any other country.

Comment: What kind of long-stay visa are you applying for? If it's a visa you are entitled to (“délivré de plein droit” like a family reunion visa), an appeal will require a lawyer but it may make sense. If it's not (discretionary visas like work or student visas), it's almost completely hopeless, the state doesn't even owe you a justification and is given a lot of leeway by the courts. Expect to pay in the low thousands at the very least, more if it turns out your case is more complex.

Comment: @Relaxed It's a talent passport visa for long term as I have work offer from France. Do you think I have any chance to have successful appeal?

Comment: I obviously have very little information to go by but it does not sound promising to be honest. @phoog's comment about new evidence is also spot on. French administrative courts will not consider any new evidence. In fact, even arguments have to be made in writing, in French, before the court's session (unlike civil or criminal proceedings). If you really want to pursue this, you would need to hire a lawyer to help you prepare a new application and navigate the appeal (and yes, a lawyer is neither cheap nor easy to find).

Comment: Finally, you have to factor in the fact that an appeal will take a couple of years, will there still be a job for you after that?

Comment: @Relaxed am more keen to remove this refusal from my record and have clean record to avoid any serious issue for my future visa applications.  
"Appeal will take couple of year" that does not sounds good as I have not much time left in UK.

Comment: @Stark It makes sense but it still seems extremely difficult. The issue with the delay is that even if a court would cancel the previous decision, the consulate would legally be able to refuse it again, ruling that it has no purpose (because you don't have a job anymore).

Comment: @Relaxed If court remove my previous refusal and it's reasons then it can help me to avoid any difficulty for other countries visa if they still do not issue me new visa. But they acknowledge that previous refusal was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to appeal instead of filing a new application, you should probably heed the advice of your previous consultant. Handling an appeal likely qualifies as a legal matter reserved to qualified lawyer, notaries, or other professionals. Indeed, if a consultant goes beyond mere assistance with a visa application, it would be a criminal offence providing legal advice without authorization in France.

The French bar association provides the membership list with specialization here: https://www.cnb.avocat.fr/fr/annuaire-des-avocats-de-france

There are also online website like Jurifit.fr and juritravail.fr where you may consult lists of some lawyers registered on their sites and possibly contact a lawyer online.

If you have a sponsor or other French contacts (e.g. your employer or educational institution), they can be useful in providing a list of specialized lawyers.

Comment: In addition to @xngtng answer, in the 'Mentions de spécialisation ' list you should select 'Droit des étrangers et de la nationalité'

Comment: @xngtng Thank you for your answer.  I probably go with appeal option instead of new application as I have UK police character certificate with no criminal record to support my appeal. I need the services of a English speaking lawyers as I don't speak french.

Comment: @audionuma I am looking for services of an English speaking lawyer.

Comment: @Stark well just add the 'langues' = 'anglais' criteria in the form. Notice that the results are randomly sorted and limited to 200 results. you can also add a 'barreau' or 'city' criteria which are geographic constraints.

Comment: @audionuma thanks for your response. Do you know an estimate amount need to pay to lawyers if matter goes to court if appeal remains unsuccessful ?

Comment: @Stark "I probably go with appeal option instead of new application as I have UK police character certificate with no criminal record to support my appeal": I don't know about France specifically but in most legal systems it's not helpful to introduce new evidence in an appeal -- the court will refuse to consider it.  An appeal will be successful if you can establish that the original decision maker made the wrong decision _taking into account the evidence available at the time._  To introduce new evidence for a visa application, one should generally submit a fresh application.

Comment: @phoog I understood your point about new evidence.Why I did not submit police character certificate with France visa application? Because it was not the requirement of visa. I had submitted police character certificate when I applied for UK visa from Pakistan as it was their requirement and now I have police character certificate from Pakistan and UK but don't know how to establish that decision was wrong based on the documents I provided with visa application as I only submitted my degree, birth certificate, passport with documents from employer.